# How to solve $z^3+z+1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

I have troubles with solving an equation
$$z^3+z+1=0$$
in complex numbers. I know that in real numbers we can use Cardano's formula and it's clear to me. But what about the situation when $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: why not get the real root and then get the roots of quadratic equation hence formed? Probably because of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSi2y.png

Comment: In the complex, a number has three cubic roots and Cardano's solutions are multiple, but only three combinations are valid.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi so it's not reasonable to calculate it. Is there another way? Or is it simply sufficient to say that "we ought to do it this way, but it's very complicated in evaluating"?

Comment: And you'll need Galois theory to understand the deep reason why the roots have an expression with $+,\times, \sqrt[n]{.}$ and complex roots of unity

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0  OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283046/what-are-the-roots-of-the-equation-8x3-6x1-0 OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203364/solve-the-following-equation-x3-3x-sqrtx2

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Given the (real) cube roots $A,B$ such that the real root is $A+B,$ the other two roots  are $A\omega + B \omega^2, $ and $A \omega^2 + B \omega,$ where $\omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt 3}{2}$ is a cube root of $1$ Note that $\omega^2 = \bar{\omega},$ so that these two  roots are complex conjugates

Comment: @Novice Buraian offers an answer without using Cardano although the complexity to solve it is a little higher. But....to find the real root you'll need either of the methods proposed.

Comment: @reuns Could you tell me more about this theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the (real) cube roots $A,B$ in Cardano's mthod, so that the real root of your cubic is $A+B,$ the other two roots are complex conjugates, given by
$$  A \omega + B \omega^2 $$
$$  A \omega^2 + B \omega $$
where
$$ \omega = \frac{-1 + i\sqrt 3}{2}$$
and
$$ \omega^2 = \bar{\omega}  $$
and $$\omega^3 = 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

The Cardano formula gives the real root
$$a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}-9}{18}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{93}+9}{18}} <0$$
Then, factorize the equation as
$$x^3+x+1=(x-a)(x^2+ax-\frac1a)=0$$
where the quadratic factor gives the pair of complex roots
$$x_{1,2}=\frac12\left( -a\pm i \sqrt{1-\frac3a}\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

$$ z = re^{i \theta}$$

Or,

$$ r^3 \left[  e^{i3 \theta} \right] + re^{i \theta} + 1 =0$$

$$ r^3 \left[ \sum_{k=even}^{2}\binom{3}{k} \cos^k \theta (i)^{3-k} \sin^{3-k} \theta+ \sum_{k=odd}^{3} \binom{3}{k} \cos^k \theta (i)^{3-k} \sin^{3-k} \theta \right] + r e^{i \theta} + 1 =0$$

Equating real and imaginary part to zero,

$$ r^3 \left[ \sum_{k=odd}^3 \binom{3}{k} (i)^{3-k} \sin^{3-k} \theta \cos^k \theta  \right] + r \cos \theta + 1 = 0$$

Or,

$$ r^3 \left[ \sum_{k=0}^1 \binom{3}{2k+1}  (-1)^{1+k} \sin^{2-2k} \theta \cos^{2k+1} \theta  \right] + r \cos \theta + 1 = 0 \tag{1}$$

And,

$$  r^3 \left[\sum_{k=even}^2 \binom{3}{k} \cos^k \theta (i)^{3-k} \sin^{3-k} \theta  \right] + r i \sin \theta = 0$$

Or,

$$  r^2 \left[\sum_{k=0}^1 \binom{3}{2k} \cos^{2k} \theta (-1)^{k+1}  \sin^{3-2k} \theta  \right] +  \sin \theta = 0 \tag{2}$$

I'll leave you with solving the trignometric equation of (1) an d (2)